# Circonflex and backtick cannot be typed in most applications

Tags: opensuse, keyboard-layout

OpenSuse does not ship with my preferred keyboard layout (NEO2). It is a German keyboard layout but not the standard German keyboard layout. After downloading and executing the install script, I was able to type using that layout after login.

However, the characters circonflex (^) and backtick (`) can only be typed in Firefox and Emacs. I attempted to type them various other applications (e.g. Konsole, speedcrunch, Dolphin, Kate) with only a space appearing (I press the modifier key followed by a space). It's not like they can't print these characters but that it's actually a space. I confirmed this by trying to type

```
echo "^" > file1
echo " " > file2
sha256sum file*
```

I can, however, copy and paste the characters from Firefox or Emacs, upon which they are correctly printed. How can I enter these characters in a normal way?